# SFINAE example not clear

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct has_typedef_foobar {
    // Types "yes" and "no" are guaranteed to have different sizes,
    // specifically sizeof(yes) == 1 and sizeof(no) == 2.
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(typename C::foobar*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    // If the "sizeof" the result of calling test<T>(0) would be equal to the sizeof(yes),
    // the first overload worked and T has a nested type named foobar.
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

struct foo {    
    typedef float foobar;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << has_typedef_foobar<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_typedef_foobar<foo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Above example shows SFAINE .

- Here I am not able to understand why sizeof(yes)==1 and
  sizeof(no)==2.
- Since test is static function , there should be some
  definition of test function also  .But code here compiles fine
  without defining test function

Comment: sizeof(function(arg)) does not call the function, so the function does not have to be defined for this construct to work

Comment: I clearly understand sizeof(char[1])==1 and sizeof(char[2])==2 but is there a specific reason why "no" was taken as char[2].we could have taken "no" as typedef int no.Basic logic I understood , but I am feeling I have missed something here.

Comment: @Alien01 `sizeof(int)` is compiler and platform-dependent, while char[1] and char[2] are guaranteed to have different sizes (and furthermore, `sizeof(char)` is always 1).

Comment: AFAIK, sizeof(type) for any of the builtin types that isn't char is implementation-defined based on the architecture it's being built for. For example, sizeof(int) would be 2 on a 16-bit machine, but 4 on a 32-bit machine. Ergo, using arrays of char gives exact size guarantees.

Comment: `sizeof(int)`could be `1` on a platform with large enough `char`s

Comment: @Grizzly From what I understand, there _are_ embedded platforms where `sizeof(int)` is 1 (and `char` has 32 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `sizeof(char)` is defined to be equal to 1. Since `yes` is a typedef for an array of one char, its size has to be one. Likewise, since `no` is a typedef for an array of two chars, its size must be `2 * sizeof(char)`, which is 2.

2) The function `test` is never called, so the definition is unnecessary - the `sizeof` operator is a compile-time operation, so the compiler just looks at the size of the return type of the instantiation of test with the specified template parameter. Because it's not called, a definition is unnecessary, similar to making private non-defined copy constructor in order to make a class non copy-constructable.

Comment: so it could also be done like typedef int no; . I feel "no" is defined as array of 2 chars rather than int just to minimize size?

Comment: It could be, but you lose guarantees that way. See my comment on the question for a fuller answer.

Comment: @Alien01: Not without relying on platform specific behaviour, since there are no guarantees that `sizeof(int)>1`. There is nothing keeping char from being 16 or 32bit (I think I remember a platform where it is even 64bit).

Comment: @Alien01 A quick search gives [this](http://www.freescale.com/infocenter/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.freescale.doc.mcu.hcs08_compiler%2Fdoc%2FHIDO_OPT_TYPE_MANAGEMENT.html), a compiler for a microcontroller with a configurable size of `char`, it can be 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits, whatever is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: In the vocabulary of the standard: a function requires a definition if it is in an expression which is "potentially evaluated" (or if it is virtual, but that doesn't apply here).  The operand to `sizeof` is explicitly stated to be "unevaluated".